# Selection of Rigged Characters

Tags: rigging

I got a .blend file which containing only rigged characters, now I am copying the whole character to another .blend file to combine it and animate it. The problem is when I am working on multiple characters on the 'another' blend file I can't select the whole rigged character but just left clicking it. Can anyone tell me how to select rigged characters with their body at once? Thanks!

Comment: Select by left clicking if not the default keymap setting, are you sure you didn't customize it?

Comment: It can't be selected by left clicking, do you mean right clicking it? I right clicked the body but it didn't select the rig and the elements.

Comment: What about using `Shift+RMB` and click on both?

Comment: What is the RMB Key?

Comment: @user294928 RMB=Right Mouse Button

Comment: That may depend on how you are 'copying' to the second file. If you are linking then you need to make a proxy of the armature to animate it.

Comment: I press A to select the whole character on the character file and copy selection to buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you will use `File> Link` to bring a mesh into another blend file. You then navigate to the .blend file, which will open up like a directory in the file browser. If the rig is well-designed, there will be a **Group** directory inside. Go into the group directory and select the group.

If there is no Group folder, navigate to the **Object** folder and <kbd>Shift + LMB</kbd> the objects that you want.

Linking provides several advantages. Not the least of which is that you can edit your rig without requiring any changes in your asset file. Invaluable when working with other people who are your modelers. However you could also `Append` which makes it so it points to the file, instead of copying it. This is useful working with other people, or when you what to change the asset directly.